# Last two digits of $2^5+2^{5^2} +\dots +2^{5^{2015}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $$N=2^5+2^{5^2} +\dots +2^{5^{2015}}.$$ Find the last two digits of $N$.

It suffices to find $N \mod 100$. And I observed that $2^{20+n}=2^n\pmod{100}$ for $n \ge 2$. So is the answer just $(2015)(32) \mod 100 =80$?

Comment: Don't use parentheses, use brackets like these for your exponents { }

Answer (score 5):

Notice that

$$
32^5=2^{25} \equiv 2^{10}\cdot 2^{10} \cdot 2^5 \equiv 24^2 \cdot 32 \equiv 32 \mod 100
$$

(I think what you wrote there does not make sense as stated)

and it follows that

$$
2^{5^k} \equiv 32 \mod 100
$$

for all $k\ge 1$

So indeed

$$
2^{5}+2^{5^2}+\cdots+2^{5^{2015}} \equiv 32 \cdot 2015 \equiv 64480 \equiv 80  \mod 100
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2015} 2^{\left(5^k\right)} \pmod {100}$, then you can compute:

$$X_4 \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2015} 2^{\left(5^k\right)} \pmod 4$$
$$X_{25} \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2015} 2^{\left(5^k\right)} \pmod {25}$$

$X_4 \equiv 0$ in each term.  $2^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod {25}$, this you seem to have noted.  So

$$X_{25} \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2015} 2^{\left(5^k \text{ mod } 20\right)} \pmod {25}$$

$5^k \equiv 5 \pmod 20$ for $k \ge 1$, so

$$X_{25} \equiv \sum_{k=1}^{2015} 2^5 \equiv 2015\cdot 32 \equiv 5\pmod {25}$$

And $$\begin{cases} X \equiv 5 \pmod {25} \\ X\equiv 0 \pmod 4 \end{cases}$$ only has 1 solution $\pmod {100}$.